# Interactive Brokers API Data stream returns only NaN values

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, tws

I have a class that establishes several market data streams and stores them in an array. Then another function within the same class accesses the array and requests data from the streams, but all the values are coming out as NaN.

Here is an example:

```py
 from ib_insync import *

 class Trading:
     def __init__(...):
         self.dataStreams = []
         self.conn = IB()  #establish connecting to the api
         self.tickers = [('BMW', 'IBIS'), ('BAYN', 'IBIS'),  .. ]

     def _stream_data(self): # this function established the data stream and appends it to an array
         for contract in self.tickers:
              stock = Stock(contract[0], contract[1], 'EUR')
              stream = self.conn.reqMktData(stock, '', False, False)
              self.dataStreams.append(stream)
              self.conn.sleep(1)

    def start(self):
        self._stream_data()  # fill the datastream array
        print(self.dataStreams[0].last + self.dataStreams[1].last)  # so this should return the sum of two prices, but it does not
```

So when I initialize the above class in the interpreter:

```py
 strategy = Trading()
 strategy.start()
```

`strategy.start()` will print `NaN` because the data from the streams are coming as `NaN`. However if I access the datastreams array from the strategy object like so:

```
strategy.dataStreams[0].last
```

it will print the last price correctly.

I think that this issue is related to the nature of IB api working asynchronously, but I do not have enough experience to figure a work around. 
I need to make other functions withing the class to be able to retrieve data from the streams and perform calculations.

Is it possible to do with the logic above? or do i have to move the data streams in to a separate class and initialize it separately in order to be able to access the data?

Comment: The problem look being in the network connection or `self.conn.reqMktData` result. Please, post the code.

Comment: reqMktData is an Interactive Brokers API function. Here is a link to the doc: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/md_request.html

Comment: You're using ib_insync which is not the native IB API at all...

Comment: it is simply a wrapper around it